# How to resolve :first argument must be an iterable of pandas objects, you passed an object of type "DataFrame" in Pandas

Tags: pandas, csv, concatenation

I am getting this error:

```sh
first argument must be an iterable of pandas objects, you passed an object of type "DataFrame".
```

My code:

```py
for f in
    glob.glob("C:/Users/panksain/Desktop/aovaNALYSIS/CX AOV/Report*.csv"):
    data = pd.concat(pd.read_csv(f,header = None, names = ("Metric Period", "")), axis=0, ignore_index=True)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`concat` takes a list of dataframes to concat with. You can first build the list and then do the concat at last:

```
dfs = []
for f in glob.glob("C:/Users/panksain/Desktop/aov aNALYSIS/CX AOV/Report*.csv"):
    dfs.append(pd.read_csv(f,header = None, names = ("Metric Period", "")))
data = pd.concat(dfs, axis=0, ignore_index=True)
```